azure.identity._exceptions.CredentialUnavailableError: Azure CLI not found on path
I am running a code in my azure environment. When I use pipeline it gives the below error.

azure.identity._exceptions.CredentialUnavailableError: Azure CLI not found on path

I am not using AzureCliCredential in my code. I am using only ServicePrincipal Authentication.
Any idea why this error occurs?
I am running a python code where I use ServicePrincipalAuthentication from the package azureml.core.authentication.
The same file when executed through in azure pipeline, it provides the error

azure.identity._exceptions.CredentialUnavailableError: Azure CLI not found on path

How a python file works fine separately and throws this issue in pipeline.yaml alone.
That too before even entering into my python file a warning comes up as
WARNING:azure.identity._internal.decorators:AzureCliCredential.get_token_info failed: Azure CLI not found on path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_3cb62e970f03d906e78d9ce1bb7fcc17/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/identity/_internal/decorators.py", line 23, in wrapper
    token = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_3cb62e970f03d906e78d9ce1bb7fcc17/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/identity/_credentials/azure_cli.py", line 125, in get_token_info
    return self._get_token_base(*scopes, options=options)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_3cb62e970f03d906e78d9ce1bb7fcc17/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/identity/_credentials/azure_cli.py", line 147, in _get_token_base
    output = _run_command(command, self._process_timeout)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_3cb62e970f03d906e78d9ce1bb7fcc17/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/identity/_credentials/azure_cli.py", line 217, in _run_command
    raise CredentialUnavailableError(message=CLI_NOT_FOUND)
azure.identity._exceptions.CredentialUnavailableError: Azure CLI not found on path

Tried installing azure-cli but version is mismatching with other packages.

Can you brief the issue more for better understanding? @Stackuser

sure, added more info

Can you share more details about how to configure azure pipeline and sample of the python code? What kind of agent are you using?

Can you check if any other resources using Azure CLI credential implicitly in the pipeline? @Stackuser
